# Namespacing Dot operator in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm watching a tutorial on C# and I was under the assumption that by using the following declaration would be redundant code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

By using the UnityEngine namespace, shouldn't that already include the UI members?

Comment: C# namespaces are not "cumulative" in that a child namespace does not import the classes of itself & its' parent.

Comment: No, `UnityEngine.UI` is a separate namespace, just like `System.IO` is a separate namespace to `System`.